# Kafka Logstash Avro integration failing

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, avro

I am trying to consume a topic from Kafka using Avro Deserializer in Logstash and getting the below error.

Here is my Logstash Config file input

```
    input {
      kafka {
       bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9911,kafka2:9911,kafka3.com:9911"
       topics => "EMS.Elastic_new"
       auto_offset_reset => earliest
       group_id => "logstash106"
      ssl_truststore_location => "/apps/opt/application/elasticsearch/logstash-7.1.1/kafka_files/kafka.client.truststore.jks"
      ssl_truststore_password => "xxxx"
      security_protocol => "SSL"
      key_deserializer_class => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
      value_deserializer_class => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
      codec => avro_schema_registry {
        endpoint => "https://kafka1:9990" 
        subject_name => "EMS.Elastic_new"
        schema_id => 170
        schema_uri => "/apps/opt/application/elasticsearch/logstash-7.1.1/kafka_files/ticketInfo.avsc"
        tag_on_failure => true
        register_schema => true
      }
    }
  }
output {
     elasticsearch {
       index => "smd_etms_es2"
       document_id => "%{tktnum}%"
       action => "update"
       doc_as_upsert => "true"
       retry_on_conflict => 5
       hosts => ["npes1:9200"]
  }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}


[ERROR][logstash.inputs.kafka ]
Unable to create Kafka consumer from given configuration {:kafka_error_message=>org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: 
Failed to construct kafka consumer, :cause=>io.confluent.common.config.
ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" 
which has no default value.} [2019-07-26T16:58:22,736][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline ]
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin. Pipeline_id:main
```

I have provided avro_uri in codec however, the settings is not been read by the logstash.

Comment: here is my logstash.conf

Comment: Please find the logstash.conf attached.

Comment: Also, here is the list of jars that i added to the logstash:         

kafka-avro-serializer-5.0.0.jar
kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar
common-config-5.0.0.jar
common-utils-5.0.0.jar
kafka-schema-registry-client-5.0.0.jar
avro-1.8.2.jar
avro-maven-plugin-1.8.2.jar
avro-compiler-1.8.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

Comment: Try setting your serializers to just the byte array ones https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry/blob/master/lib/logstash/codecs/avro_schema_registry.rb#L87

Answer (score 0):

> Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url"

Comes from setting

```
  key_deserializer_class => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
  value_deserializer_class => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
```

Based on the [example code](https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry/blob/master/lib/logstash/codecs/avro_schema_registry.rb#L87), it seems it wants you just to use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` for both, then I assume `avro_codec` does the schema management on its own using the `endpoint` parameter